# Omit variable label in gtsummary tbl_summary

Tags: r, gtsummary

Using gtsummary version 1.7.0, I am making a table with some statistics of a continuous variable:

```
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = c(rep("A", 50), rep("B", 50)))
dat %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = y,
    type = x ~ "continuous2",
    statistic = x ~ c("{mean}", "{min}", "{max}"),
    label = x ~ "this row should not exist"
  ) %>%
  modify_caption(caption = "Some basic statistics for variable x")
```

As I only have one variable, and the description of the variable will be in the table caption, I want to omit the variable label.
Changing "this row should not exist" to NULL (shows "x" instead) or to "" (shows an empty line instead) does not quite get me there, because I want to get rid of that whole line. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `modify_table_body()` function to header row. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.7.1'

dat <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = c(rep("A", 50), rep("B", 50)))
dat |>
  tbl_summary(
    by = y,
    type = x ~ "continuous2",
    statistic = x ~ c("{mean}", "{min}", "{max}")
  ) |>
  # remove header row
  modify_table_body(
    ~ .x |> 
      dplyr::filter(!(variable %in% "x" & row_type %in% "label"))
  ) |> 
  as_kable() # convert to kable to display on stackoverflow
```

| **Characteristic** | **A**, N = 50 | **B**, N = 50 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mean | 26 | 76 |
| Minimum | 1 | 51 |
| Maximum | 50 | 100 |

<sup>Created on 2023-05-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I want to use this in a function where one of the parameters is the variable to be included (x in this case). How can '.x' be replaced so this code will work whatever variable is included, that is, how can we remove the row without naming the variable?